# Having difficulty in evaluating limit of the product

Tags: real-analysis, limits, riemann-integration

I am trying to solve past year exam problem. I need to show that $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\left(1+\frac{2^4}{n^4}\right)^{1/2}\left(1+\frac{3^4}{n^4}\right)^{1/3}..\left(2\right)^{1/n}\right)= e^{\pi^2/32}$.

I am completely stucked. I need help to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuing from Jaideep Khare's answer,
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac 1x \ln \left(1+x^4\right) d x&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}  \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty(-1)^{i+1}\frac{x^{4i}}{i}\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i+1} \frac{x^{4i-1}}{i} \,dx\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i+1} \int_0^1 \frac{x^{4i-1}}{i}\,dx \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^{i+1}\frac{1}{4i^2} \\
&=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i^2} \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{32}\end{align}$$
The final sum is a standard result (or lemma) related to the Basel problem. Interchange of the sum and limit needs to be justified, I leave to the reader.

Comment: Many many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for continuing and concluding the sum. +1 for you ^_^

Answer (score 6):

Let $${\rm A}=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\left(1+\frac{2^4}{n^4}\right)^{1/2}\left(1+\frac{3^4}{n^4}\right)^{1/3}..\left(2\right)^{1/n}\right)$$

Taking $\ln$ both the sides,

$$\ln {\rm A} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{r=1}^n \frac 1r  \ln \left( 1+ \left( \frac rn \right)^4 \right)$$

$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1n \sum_{r=1}^n \frac 1{r/n} \ln \left( 1+ \left( \frac rn \right)^4 \right)= \int_0^1 \frac 1x \ln \left(1+x^4\right) {\rm d} x$$

Comment: @B.Mehta Yes you're right I totally forgot to write it. Thanks for noticing. Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. Last integration seems to me difficult. I am trying.